# On the logarithm of the fractional part Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, zeta-functions, fractional-part

Let $\{\}$ denote the fractional part function, then does the following integral admit a closed-form ?

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\ln\bigg(\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}\bigg)dx$$

Comment: Highly doubt it. Playing a bit with this in Wolfram alpha, it seems as though this will be an infinite series of very complicated terms.

Comment: @SmileyCraft: I actually don't think the terms are terribly complicated, but I do agree outside of an infinite series, there isn't much hope for an expression involving only elementary functions.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer but provides an infinite series expression.

Upon using the $u$-substitution $u=1/x$, we have

$$
\int_0^1 x\ln\left(\left\{\frac1x\right\}\right)\,dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(\{u\})}{u^3}\,du=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\ln(u-n)}{u^3}\,du.
$$
Now using the substitution $x=\ln(u-n)$, the series becomes
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x e^x}{(e^x+n)^3}\,dx.
$$
Evaluating this last integral via integration by parts gives
$$
-\frac{1+(n+1) \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{ 2n^2 (n+1)}.
$$
Inserting this in for the integral and after doing a little bit of algebra and simplifying, the last sum is equivalent to
$$
-\frac12\left(-1+\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\frac1n)}{n^2}\right).
$$

Altogether, this gives
$$
\int_0^1 x\ln\left(\left\{\frac1x\right\}\right)\,dx=-\frac12\left(-1+\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(1+\frac1n)}{n^2}\right)\approx-0.754071
$$
where I used Mathematica for the last approximation. I don't think there is much hope for the last sum to simplify because you would have to deal with a sum of $\zeta(s)$ evaluated at odd positive integers, for which there is no known elementary expression.

Comment: I have got the same result, thank you indeed

Comment: @KaysTomy: You are welcome.